# How to load spring context xml file in CamelBlueprintTestSupport and how to get datasource object in spring context xml

Tags: spring, apache-camel, jbossfuse

How to load spring context xml file in CamelBlueprintTestSupport and how to get datasource object in spring context xml, and the issue is i have got a Exception like **java.lang.NullPointerException at com.hotel.common.persistence.dao.DAOFactory.getDAO(DAOFactory.java:27)** my assumption is DAOFactory class is not getting the mapper classes. is it correct?

i have share with you my sample code

This is my **Test class**

public class ContextRouteGetAvailabilityXmlTest extends CamelBlueprintTestSupport {

```
@Override
protected String getBlueprintDescriptor() {
    return "OSGI-INF/blueprint/context-beans.xml,OSGI-INF/blueprint/context-config.xml,OSGI-INF/blueprint/context-route-getAvailability.xml";
}


@Override
protected void addServicesOnStartup(Map<String, KeyValueHolder<Object, Dictionary>> services){
    BasicDataSource datasource = new BasicDataSource();

    datasource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    datasource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://my ip:3306/test");
    datasource.setUsername("test");
    datasource.setPassword("test1");
    datasource.setConnectionProperties("useUnicode=yes;characterEncoding=utf8;");

    services.put("dataSourceMySQL", asService(datasource, null));
}
```

}

And this is my **spring context.xml** file

```
<osgi:reference id="dataSourceMySQL" interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

<bean id="mybatisConfig" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
    <constructor-arg value="/META-INF/config/mybatis-config.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactoryBean" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMySQL" />
    <property name="configLocation" ref="mybatisConfig" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactoryBean" />
</bean>

<!-- scan for mappers and let them be autowired -->
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.sia.csl.hotel.common.persistence.mapper" />
    <property name="sqlSessionTemplateBeanName" value="sqlSession" />
</bean>

<bean id="daoFactory"
    class="com.common.persistence.dao.DAOFactory" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSGi Blueprint is not supporting Spring XML files, but only Blueprint XML files. So you cannot load Spring XML files with `CamelBlueprintTestSupport`. Instead you can use regular spring, via camel-test-spring module.

If you run on OSGi then Spring XML files (Spring-DM) is deprecated and EOL, and should **not** be used. Instead you should migrate your Spring XML files to OSGI Blueprint files.

Comment: This way i tried to load the db and i have share with you my DAOFactory.java file

Answer (score 0):

This way i tried to load the db and i have share with you my **DAOFactory.java** file

public class DAOFactory   {

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DAOFactory.class);

private static BundleContext bundleContext;
private static SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate;

public static void setBundleContext(BundleContext arg0) {
    bundleContext = arg0;
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public static Object getDAO(Class DaoClassName) throws InvalidSyntaxException {
    logger.debug("getDAO sqlSessionTemplate: "+sqlSessionTemplate);
    if(sqlSessionTemplate == null ) {
        setBundleContext(FrameworkUtil.getBundle(DAOFactory.class).getBundleContext());
        sqlSessionTemplate = getSqlSession() ;
        logger.debug("Received sqlSessionTemplate: "+sqlSessionTemplate);
    }
    return sqlSessionTemplate.getMapper(DaoClassName);
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() throws InvalidSyntaxException {
        final String filter = "(org.springframework.context.service.name=" + bundleContext.getBundle().getSymbolicName() + ")";
        logger.debug("Symbolic Name: "+filter);
        final ServiceReference[] applicationContextRefs = bundleContext.getServiceReferences(ApplicationContext.class.getName(), filter);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final ApplicationContext applicationContext = (ApplicationContext) bundleContext.getService(applicationContextRefs[0]);
        logger.debug("applicationContext: "+applicationContext);
        return applicationContext;

}
```